# How to divide values in one column to create 2 new columns from DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, character

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below (of course in real DataFrame I have many more columns):

```
COL1                               | COL2  | ...  | COLn
-----------------------------------|-------|------|--------
ABC_20220830_CP_6M_BEFORE_100_200  |XXX    | .... | ...
XXA_20220830_CP_6M_BEFORE_150_300  |AAA    | .... | ...
KKTY_20220830_CP_6M_BEFORE_150_300 |TTT    | .... | ...
OOP_20220830_CP_6M_BEFORE_500_600  |TYTT   | .... | ...
```

And I would like to modify column "COL1" to have something like below based on following conditions:

- in COL1 the center of each value is the same, i.e: "20220830_CP_6M_BEFORE" only values before and after mentioned part of string could be different
- I need to create 2 columns based on values in "COL1":

  - the first column "COL1a": from the begining of value to the "_20220830"
  - the second column "COL1b": from "CP_6M_BEFORE_" to the end of value

| COL1_a | COL1_b | COL2 | .... | COLn | COL1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC_20220830 | CP_6M_BEFORE_100_200 | XXX | ... | ... | ABC_20220830_CP_6M_BEFORE_100_200 |
| XXA_20220830 | CP_6M_BEFORE_150_300 | AAA | ... | ... | XXA_20220830_CP_6M_BEFORE_150_300 |
| KKTY_20220830 | CP_6M_BEFORE_150_300 | TTT | ... | ... | KKTY_20220830_CP_6M_BEFORE_150_300 |
| OOP_20220830 | CP_6M_BEFORE_500_600 | TYTT | ... | ... | OOP_20220830_CP_6M_BEFORE_500_600 |

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `CP_6M_BEFORE` as your delimiter?
You should be able to extract the first part of your string by using pandas's `split` method:

```
mydelimiter = 'CP_6M_BEFORE'
df['COL1_a'] = df['COL1'].str.split(mydelimiter).str[0]
```

The second part you can build using your delimiter as a prefix:

```
df['COL1_b'] = mydelimiter+df['COL1'].str.split(mydelimiter).str[1].astype(str)
```

If you are looking for a more robust solution, you may use the underscore (`_`) as your delimiter and then create column `COL1_a` and `COL1_b` from the individual strings output by the split method.

Comment: Sheldon, almost good, but when I use your solution I have redundant "_" at the beginning of each value in COL1_b, how to delete that "_" ?

Comment: Good point. Then you may skip adding the extra underscore after `mydelimiter`. In other words, use `df['COL1_b'] = mydelimiter+df['COL1'].str.split(mydelimiter).str[1].astype(str)`.
I will update my answer accordingly.